# Insert sql rows instead of deleted rows will make database size increase or still the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large database its MDF file nearly 190 GB. When I delete a large number of old rows the MDF size doesn't get reduced. What will happen when insert new records into my database? Will the size of the data-files increase or does the new records fill the available / free space created by the deleted rows. I can't shrink the database or copy it into a new empty one. This is a production database and doing any of these operations would require me to stop the website which is not feasible for me. Should I acquire more disk space from my hosting provider???

Comment: It all depends, but in many cases you will have to reorganize or rebuild indexes before you can shrink files. Depending on your design you may or may not be able to reuse this space immediately for new rows.

Comment: No sense in rebuilding the index @Piotr. [Shrinking will cause them to fragment A LOT](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/). The catch 22 here is you might say *Ok, shrink and then rebuild indexs!* But, as the post explains, the data file will grow to build out the new copy of the indexes and then drop the old ones... all of a sudden our file has grown again, though likely not to it's original size since the OP stated they purged data.

Comment: If the whole table is a regular non-partitioned B-Tree, you are 100% correct. If some of your data are stored in a Columnstore index, you need to reorg it to physically delete the rows. If you partition by time, rebuilding partitions where you deleted 99% of data may help. And of course, you shouldn't be shrinking the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What will happen when insert new records into my database? Will the size of the data-files increase or does the new records fill the available / free space created by the deleted rows

It will fill the free space.

> I can't shrink the database

[You shouldn't](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/), either. At most, you should ONLY use `SHRINKFILE`. However, this shouldn't be something you do *often* either. It should only be done when (by accident) your data-files have grown abnormally large. Most databases continue to grow as time passes since most aren't *purged* of any data. Thus, it's common to require more space (see below)

> Should I acquire more disk space from my hosting provider?

As you insert more data, and are unable to delete any "old" data, then yes, you would need more disk space. Note that though your datafiles are a certain size, that doesn't mean they are full. You [can check](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/) the disk *free space* via a report. [This blog](https://sqlzen.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/difference-between-unallocated-and-unused-space/) and others explain the difference between *Unallocated, Unused, and Free Space*